# Find matching row(s) in other range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a column containing a category based on a set of categories and a match/regex string from another range. My example is:

[image: example]

I can't find any answered questions here which explain to me how this can be done, if it can. So am asking here if anyone can help or point me toward an answer I've probably missed!

Neither the category or data ranges will be a static number of rows. I'd like to have a formula which simply produces something like this:

[image]

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, "["&TEXTJOIN( , 1, B2:B)&"]")))
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, "["&TEXTJOIN( , 1, 
 REGEXREPLACE(C2:C, "[\.\*]", ))&"]")))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E2:E, "["&TEXTJOIN( , 1, 
 REGEXREPLACE(C2:C, "[\.\*]", ))&"]")), {
 REGEXREPLACE(C2:C, "[\.\*]", ), B2:B}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

---

### update 2

first of all, learn your regex: **https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax**

change your C column to:

```
.*(A).*
.*(B).*
.*(C).*
```

then use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E3:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C3:C)))),,9^9))), {
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(C3:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E3:E, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C3:C)))),,9^9)))))), B3:B}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

or shorter:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E3:E, "["&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C3:C)&"]")), { 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(C3:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(E3:E, "["&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C3:C)&"]"))))), B3:B}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @player0, not quite what I'm after, that's matching the regex of cells B3:B, i.e. "[ABC]". I'm after matching the regex from column C of B3:C with the context of cells of E3:E, and resulting in the corresponding value from column B or B3:C (cell/column referenced from original examples).

Comment: real sample would be much more helpfull

Comment: Here's a real sample, it's the example above that has everything in it to illustrate what I'm after ... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4abOrWZiJCVEatdVV7iGTFSC5CWYJC0n3GI7FBCsBE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks again @player0, but no luck I'm afraid. I think you're going about this assuming the regexes in C are fixed format, not mutable regexes. You're basically erasing every '.*' from each regex, assuming there'll be only a single character remaining and so concating the regexreplace results into '[...]' regex.

Comment: I have also posted this on the Google Sheets support forum and have some very good answers so far, the solution I will post here as an answer when the issue has been solved.